# Set all Woocommerce products with same height but variable width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

In my [site](http://%20http://catalogue2.cappiello.fr/) I would like that all my products have the same height but variable width.

I tried it by UI, but it didn't work.

Any idea how to do it with CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mnemosdev said, only slightly more complex ;)

You can style the `li` items like this:

```
.fusion-carousel .fusion-carousel-item {
    height: 200px; /* set to your liking */
    width: auto !important;  /* important needed to override inline style */
}
```

but then you'll see the images get really large. So style them:

```
.fusion-carousel .fusion-carousel-item img {
    height: 200px; /* set to your liking */
    width: auto;
}
```

You actually do not need to style the li items, so start with the images, then adjust to your liking.

Comment: it works well, with wide pics, I lose ratio : look a this page : http://catalogue2.cappiello.fr/index.php/full-shop-with-sidebar/ - Ami du peuple pic ( to see original pic, just open it ) - to see what I want to achieve : http://catalogue.cappiello.fr/items/browse?sort_field=Dublin+Core%2CIdentifier

Comment: The styling I gave you was for the caroussel on the link in your question http://catalogue2.cappiello.fr/ and I did not see anything wrong with the ratio on that slider. Did you want the full-shop page styled?

Comment: it is because there is no wide pic in this carousel. Correct, I also applied your style to full-shop page. Now importing 1200 pics so you should find a wide pic in carousel ( but I don't know how long will you wait )

Comment: now, I changed it so you see it. ratio is ok, but thumb is cropped

Comment: ooo. my changes are local, that's why you don't see!

Comment: I see... the styling of the caroussel is not the same as last night when I was testing it in my console... did you add width and height attributes? ( I don't remember seeing them). Re the ratio: when you set a fixed heigth for an img, make sure there's no fixed width...

Comment: it's possible that the caroussel script reads the styles then sets inline styles causing these croppings. Maybe the script has any settings you can use? Otherwise, the only way to override its behaviour would be to use `!important` tags for the css styles you apply.

Comment: yep, it changed, but I reverted it, and now it works fine! Tx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS should have something like

```
.myCSSClass {
width: auto;
height: 100px; /* Instead of a 100px use the value you want */
}
```

EDIT (I can't comment on post yet, hence I write my comment here):

With wide images, since you are losing the ratio, I guess you could use some code snippet like bootstrap to make images responsive. If your image is set as a background from CSS you can use the background-size set to cover. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)